# Go to print page and save as pdf python

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-chrome, pdf, html-parsing

To begin with, I am wondering whether this is possible at all. So on [this web page](https://datacvr.virk.dk/data/visenhed?enhedstype=virksomhed&id=25578198&soeg=25578198) there is a Print button, if you click it, it generates a nice looking pdf report of the html. And from there on you can either download or print it. So I am wondering is it possible to go to save it as a pdf as well but invoked by a python script?

Currently, I am parsing the HTML to gather the data I need but not nearly as good and fancy looking as the generated by them.

I've also tried pdfkit but it doesn't seem to be a good idea since the data is "hidden" by drop down menus/buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use pythons builtin mechanize or [selenium rc with python](http://coreygoldberg.blogspot.co.uk/2009/09/selenium-rc-with-python-in-30-seconds.html) to navigate to the page, fill in any form details that are needed then "click" the button and specify where to download to.